# Leitura do JSON retorna vazio

Tags: php, json

Estou lendo um JSON de uma URL, conforme código abaixo:

```
$link1 = file_get_contents('http://gwmestampas.com.br/arquivo.json');

$obj = json_decode($link1);
echo $obj->event;
echo $obj["event"];


 foreach($obj as $link){
    $event = $link->event;
    $event2 = $link["event"];
    //$numOrd =  $link->resource->payment->_links->order->title;
    //$tipoPag =  $link->resource->payment->events->type;
    //$numPag =  $link->resource->payment->id;        
}; 

echo $event.'-<br>';
echo $event2.'-<br>';
echo $numOrd.'-<br>';
echo $tipoPag.'-<br>';
echo $numPag.'-<br>';
```

Tentei de várias maneiras mas sempre retorna vazio.

Comment: `foreach($obj as $link){` o json retornado não é um array que você possa de cara fazer um `foreach`, chegou a estudar o json de retorno? poderia simplesmente ler o node direto, assim: `$obj->event`

Comment: não sei eu não entendi ou vc, mas no código acima tento fazer a leitura direto, mas não retorna nada e se tento fazer a leitura dentro do foreach também retorna vazio.

Comment: mesmo `$link1` está vazio?

Comment: se estiver, pode ser que o `file_get_contents` não esteja conseguindo ler a url como se fosse um arquivo, então precisa habilitar isso assim antes do comando: `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);`. Faça um teste, se funcionar posso explicar melhor numa resposta

Comment: O $link1 recebe os dados normais vindo do $link1 = file_get_contents(.... mas depois disso não vai a diante, depois do $obj = json_decode($link1); por exemplo usando somente o echo $obj->event; deveria pelo menos mostrar algo sabendo que a estrutura é a seguinte {
  "date": "",
  "env": "",
  "event": "ORDER.CREATED",  e ai por diante.

Comment: pegando o resultado da url e validando o json aqui: https://jsonlint.com/ e aqui https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ reclama que está inválido, pode ser esse o problema

Comment: recebo esse conteúdo do wirecard, vou entrar em contato com eles, mas acredito que não vai resolver, mas vamos tentar. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O JSON retornado é inválido. Ele possui vários objetos "soltos", um seguido do outro:

```
{"date":"","env":"" ... }{"date":"","env":"", ... }
```

Repare que depois que o primeiro objeto é encerrado com `}`, já é iniciado outro objeto com `{`. Isso não é um JSON válido.

O correto seria esses objetos estarem dentro de alguma outra estrutura, como um array, por exemplo:

```
[ {"date":"","env":"" ... }, {"date":"","env":"", ... }, ... ]
```

Aí sim seria um JSON válido. No exemplo acima, temos um array: ele é delimitado por `[]` e há vírgulas separando os elementos.

O ideal é que a URL retornasse um JSON no formato correto. Se você não tem controle sobre a URL que está acessando, o único jeito é manipular a string manualmente.

---

Atenção: o código abaixo foi feito **especificamente** para o JSON em questão. É assumida a premissa de que o JSON sempre vem assim: os objetos sempre começam com `{"date":` e não há espaços entre eles. Se houver a mínima mudança no formato, ele já não funciona mais (por isso o ideal é que a URL já retornasse um JSON válido).

A ideia é transformar esta string, que contém objetos em sequência, em um array. Para isso precisamos colocar `[` no início, `]` no fim e uma vírgula entre os objetos:

```
$link1 = file_get_contents('http://gwmestampas.com.br/arquivo.json');
$obj = json_decode('['. preg_replace('/((?<!^)\{"date":)/', ',$1', $link1). ']', true);
```

A expressão regular pega a string `{"date":` (desde que não esteja no início) e coloca uma vírgula antes dela. Também coloco o `[` e `]` e passo o resultado para `json_decode`.

Assim, `$obj` terá todos os objetos, bastando iterar pelo mesmo:

```
foreach ($obj as $link) {
    echo $link['event'];
    if (array_key_exists('payment', $link['resource'])) // nem todo resource tem payment
        echo ', '. $link['resource']['payment']['_links']['order']['title'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Pelo que vi, o `resouce` pode ou não ter `payment` ou outros campos, mas aí basta ir testando se eles existem antes de acessá-los.

---

Lembrando novamente que esta é uma solução limitada. Se a string mudar (por exemplo, retorna um objeto que não começa com `{"date":`, ou qualquer outra alteração que não bata mais com nossas premissas), ele não funciona mais. Se tiver alguma propriedade `date` dentro de outro objeto interno, a regex vai inserir uma vírgula onde não deve (por sorte não tem, é por isso que nesse caso funciona). Claro que, dependendo da mudança, bastaria alterar a regex, mas ficar usando regex para manipular JSON não é o ideal.

O ideal é que o serviço retorne um JSON válido, para que você não precise ficar fazendo essas gambiarras para arrumar a string.

Comment: foi o que comentei, esse json está mal formado. esse Regex foi top pra fazer o fix :D

Comment: Agradeço muito a Resposta, entendo que não é a melhor opção, mas recebo assim e pois é de um serviço externo, vou implementar esse código e fazer uns teste para ver se fica funcional devido eventuais alterações, e como o Ricardo comentou ficou top mesmo o regex

Comment: @FabioJonasZech É, se é de um serviço externo e eles não puderem corrigir, então o jeito é ficar ajustando a regex toda vez que mudar alguma coisa (ou torcer para não mudar nunca) :-)